# compile mixed Kotlin and Java code from the command line

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to start adding some Kotlin to my Java project. To do that I need to be able to compile both Java and Kotlin files from the command line, which is fine apart from when files of different types depend on each other e.g. A.java depends on B.kt which in turn depends on C.java.

Is there any way to do this without using Gradle, Maven etc?

**Edited to clarify** thanks @Nikita for pointing out it is not clear that I want both java and Kotlin files in the same source tree

Comment: why would you not use a build tool?

Comment: I am also interested coz I want to compile mixed java/kotlin source files in memory. @Ben Haiton do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this, you will need to run two steps.

1. Run `kotlinc` targeting `*.kt` files. Add all required java *sources* on ***classpath***. Note the destination location.
2. Run `javac` targeting `*.java` files. Add `*.class` files created by step 1 to classpath.

Result is a combination of `*.class` files from both steps.

Here is a documetation on [Kotlin compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html)

Comment: Hmm I couldn't get your solution to work. If I run something like: `kotlinc src/**/*.kt -classpath src/**/*.java -d dist` then I get an error like: `error: source entry is not a Kotlin file: src/java/SomethingElse.java`. What does seem to work is `kotlinc src/**/  -d dist` followed by javac

Comment: Sorry. I did not think that you have a mix of kotlin and java files inside one source tree. Thank you for the followup

Answer (score 2):

Remember to compile **Kotlin** first, then compile **Java** with kotlin-build-classpath from first step.

simple like this:

```
1. kotlinc ./src/* -d ./buildTmp
2. javac ./src/**.java -d ./buildTmp -classpath ./buildTmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compiling-mixed-java-and-kotlin-files-on-the-command-line/1553/2

e.g.

```
kotlinc kotlinSource.kt JavaSource.java -d run.jar
```